# c# Get value of static property from the instance of a class

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, static

How do I get the value of a static property from an instance of a class? see example below...

```
abstract class A {
   public static double Foo {get; protected set;}
}

class B : A {
   static B(){
      Foo = 1;
   }
}

class C : A {
   static C(){
      Food = 2;
   }
}

class Test {
   A test = new B();

   //How do I get test.Foo ??
}
```

Comment: you would have to do B.Foo there is no test.Foo

Comment: Should be noted that it actually exists in `A` so you're not going to always get 1 from `B.Foo` and 2 from `C.Foo` as it will get set to whichever one is statically initialized last.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it wrong. I wanted to get the static property from the variable as I was not sure whether the object was a B or C. but I see now that it doesn't matter and the static property belongs to A only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static members (fields, properties, methods, etc.) are accessed via class name.

```
var x = A.Foo;
```

I think you are getting statics wrong.

Did you mean something like this?

```
abstract class A {
   public double Foo {get; protected set;}
}

class B : A {
   public B(){
      Foo = 1;
   }
}

class C : A {
   public C(){
      Foo = 2;
   }
}

class Test {
   A test = new B();
   var foo = test.Foo;
}
```